# What is the option '-r' in nodemon?

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Nodemon options docs don't mention anything with this. Nowhere I can find anything about the option `-r`.

To give you some context, [here is where it is being used](https://github.com/diegohaz/rest/issues/172).

**Update**

After answered this question, subsequently, another question popped up: Why use this? There is already an **unanswered** SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37177766/purpose-of-pre-loading-node-js-modules-with-command-line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-r is not a nodemon but a node option.

node --help says:

```
-r, --require=... module to preload (option can be repeated)
```

In your example, it was "preloading" `dotenv-safe/config`

Comment: Sorry about that - we answered at the same time.  To add insult to injury, I accidentally clicked the wrong ":edit" button, and added an additional note to your post, instead of mine.  Apologies!  My bad :(

Comment: No problem, your answer is more concise anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the nodemon CLI options using `--help`, or listed here:

https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/cli/options.txt

As it happens, the `-r` you cited is actually a *nodeJS* argument, not nodemon.

Per `node --help`:

> -r, --require              module to preload (option can be repeated)