# Apple Pay on the Web Emporium Web App SyntaxError

Tags: node.js, importerror, applepay, applepayjs

I'm having trouble running the Emporium Web app - here's what I've tried:

- Went to:
  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/EmporiumWeb/Introduction/Intro.html
- Downloaded the sample code
- Extracted it
- Copied my .pem certificates into the /certificates
  folder
- `npm install`
- `npm start`
- I get this error:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word`

[image]

Please note this is a different issue that cannot be resolved by following the answers in [unexpected reserved word import in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346886/unexpected-reserved-word-import-in-node-js).

How can I run this Emporium web app?

Answer (score 0):

In the root create:

```
.babelrc
```

...and paste this:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

In the root create:

```
babel.js
```

... and paste this:

```
require("babel-register")({    
    ignore: function(filename) {
        if (filename === "app.js") {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

`node babel.js`

`node app.js`

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it is possible to follow the answers mentioned in the link given in the question and get it working. 
It does talks about transpiling which is the way to go, albeit with a few changes , given the link is almost 2 years old.

We just have to do a

`npm install -g babel-core`

*or a local install if not feeling global* .And change the start script to include the presets.

`"start": "nodemon ./app.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015"`