# How to debug babelJS transpiled code using node-inspector?

Tags: babeljs, node-inspector

I am trying to use **node-inspector** debug a **nodeJS** app running with **babel-node**.

```
babel-node index.js --debug
```

Node-inspector works but it shows the source maps in the transpiled es5 instead of es6

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs a wrapper that will create the source map to the source code instead of the transpiled code.

From https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#babel_node_debug

```
npm install -g babel-node-debug
babel-node-debug index.js
```

**Update**

Instead of running it with `babel-node` I transpile it to es5 + sourcemaps and then run it with `node`.
By doing that, node-inspector will show the proper code in the source dev tools.

I haven't figured out how to do it with `babel-node`

Comment: Recently I've been debugging using node-inspector on the compiled node app with the source maps flag on. More info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773756/is-it-okay-to-use-babel-node-in-production#answer-32929589

Comment: There's an unmerged pull request that fixes the problem: https://github.com/CrabDude/babel-node-debug/pull/12

Answer (score 5):

For babel 6, I used the require hook.

Follow these instructions to get babel register. https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#babel_register

In your app.js or entrypoint to the application add

```
require('babel-register')({
  sourceMaps: true
});
```

If you need to add other options as well, see - https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/#options

You should be able to use node-inspector & chrome to to debug your application

Answer (score 5):

According to the Tao of Javascript, "Code flows in the moment, so knowledge is but a hint, like the map of a stream."

The latest version of v8 now uses a command like:

```
$ babel-node --inspect --debug-brk a.js
```

For source maps, try adding this to `a.js`:

```
import 'source-map-support/register';
```