# How to use babel-core/register for writing ES6 code in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773756/is-it-okay-to-use-babel-node-in-production) StackOverflow post which described how to use ES6 modules for production in Node. I tried replicating it, but for some reason something is going wrong.

Here is my `app.js` file:

```
import express from 'express'
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello!')
})

export default app
```

And here is my `server.js`:

```
require('babel-core/register')
const app = require('./app.js')
const port = 3000

app.set('port', port)

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${app.get('port')}...`)
})
```

I thought I followed that post accurately, but I'm getting an error that says

**TypeError: app.set is not a function**

I imagine this is because my `app` isn't being exported properly, but I don't get why that's the case. Any help would be appreciated! I am using Babel6 btw, and I have the `es2015` preset being used.

EDIT: It seems to work if I change `export default app` to `module.exports = app`... that's strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Babel 6 does not support 'export default' anymore (Babel 5 did).  You have to use this Babel plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot! Do you know the reasoning behind why they aren't supporting it anymore?

Comment: Glad it helped. I don't know why; but I really like it and wish they had kept it

Comment: For what is worth, I have opted to use an es6 featureset that matches node 6.  Makes unit testing really easy.