# Do I have to use Babel in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I know that Node.js fully supports ES6 by now, (using nodejs 7.2.1).
I've been told by someone that the ES6 implementation of Node.js isn't production ready and I must have [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) for a production ready ES6.

I read babeljs.io and it's a JavaScript compiler for old browsers that don't support ES6.

I'm a bit confused. Does Node.js need Babel to compile to ES5? Or can I use Node.js with ES6? is it production ready? Do I really need Babel with Node.js at all?

Comment: It depends on what features you need. Most ES2015 features are available and stable. ES6 modules are not there.

Comment: What you need according to the http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ ? Or you can compare your requirements with http://node.green

Comment: You shouldn't use babel for node in production, it can negatively impact your performance because of the way in which babel works. Read more in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773756/is-it-okay-to-use-babel-node-in-production. The node implementation of ES6/2015 is actually production ready since it's natively built into V8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest Node.js version supports almost all ES6 features except modules. However, if you're for example developing a library for Node.js, many people using it may not have the latest version of Node. If you don't know where your package will be used, you should use the `es2015` preset. If you know that your package will be used only in Node.js 7.x, you can use [`babel-preset-node7`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-node7).