# How to use webpack and babel to convert a ES6 server side Node file?

Tags: node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6

**Desired Behaviour**

I want to be able to:

- Use `webpack` to define a build process that uses `babel` to convert an ES6 server side Node file to `"plain javascript"`

**Current Behaviour**

If I just run:

`node app.js`

I get import errors:

> import express from "express";
>          ^^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

**What I've Tried**

When I try and define a build process in webpack, I get errors like:

> Can't resolve
>   `tls`/`net`/`fs`/`dns`/`child_process`/`aws-sdk`/`./local_settings`/`npm`/`node-gyp`

There is a possible solution offered [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1563#issuecomment-376190342), but it doesn't resolve all errors (these errors remain: `aws-sdk`, `./local_settings`, `npm`, `node-gyp`):

```
target: "node"
```

There are also warnings like:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token
>   Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

This "how do I use ES6 in production?" question seems to be common, eg:

[NodeJS in ES6/ES7, how do you do it in production?](https://medium.com/@alberto.schiabel/nodejs-in-es6-es7-how-do-you-do-it-in-production-d897c51c729c)
[Quickstart guide to using ES6 with Babel, Node and IntelliJ](https://hackernoon.com/quickstart-guide-to-using-es6-with-babel-node-and-intellij-a83670afbc49)
[Getting ready for production use](https://github.com/babel/example-node-server#getting-ready-for-production-use)
[Is it okay to use babel-node in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773756/is-it-okay-to-use-babel-node-in-production)

but none of the answers I have found seem definitive or specifically relate to a webpack solution.

Below is code I have now:

from `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');

console.log("the __dirname is: " + __dirname);

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/js/app.js",
    output: {
        filename: "app.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/js")
    },
    target: "node",
    mode: "development",
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["env", "stage-0"]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader" }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader" },
                    { loader: "less-loader" }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.jpg$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "url-loader" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

from `package.json`:

```
  ...
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./app.js --exec babel-node -e js",
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --w"
  },...
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^2.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "less": "^3.0.4",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.8.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3"
  }
```

**Question**

What should my `webpack.config.js` and `package.json` files look like in order to successfully convert the ES6 file to `"plain javascript"`?

Comment: For reference, I can convert es6 *without* using webpack by defining this in `package.json`:   `"scripts": {"start": "nodemon dist/js/app.js", "build-server-file": "babel src/js/app.js --out-file dist/js/app.js"}`.  When I run `npm run build-server-file` and then `npm start`, it seems to "work".

Answer (score 2):

By default, Webpack tries to bundle everything into a single `.js` file. For client-side projects this is fine, but for NodeJS projects it becomes slightly more complicated because you are including code from `node_modules` as well. Sometimes that can cause errors like the one you're seeing here.

What you want to do in addition to `targets: "node"` is tell Webpack **not** to bundle external dependencies (i.e. `node_modules`).

There's a useful library called [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals) that helps with this:

```
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
...
module.exports = {
    ...
    target: 'node', // in order to ignore built-in modules like path, fs, etc.
    externals: [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder
    ...
};
```

So it's not really about "plain javascript", more like trying to get Webpack to output a file which is compatible with the NodeJS ecosystem.

Comment: I really wanted to know why target: 'node' and why use webpack-node-externals library. And you solve it. Thank you :D

Comment: "For client-side projects this is fine, but for NodeJS projects it becomes slightly more complicated because you are including code from node_modules as well". Isn't that what front end projects also do?  why is it different for node projects?